# how does "pydub._data" and "numpy.fromsting" work in audio fingerprint?

Tags: python, numpy, pydub

```
import numpy as np
from pydub import AudioSegment

song = AudioSegment.from_mp3("Music/Jimin/trap/_Revolution (Original Mix).mp3")

tensec = song[:10]
data = np.fromstring(tensec._data,np.int16)

print tensec
print data
```

this is excerpt from audio fingerprint soft ware i am working on. I am not quite sure about few things.

1. what kind of format is tensec saved as
2. what `._data` do to tensec and what kind of format is `tensec._data` in
3. what is purpose of having `fromstring` (all I understood is that `fromstring` takes `tensec._data` and returns a array)

please help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Just about all operations you can perform on an AudioSegment return an AudioSegment (including slicing) similar to how slicing a string returns a string.

   However, slicing is done in milliseconds so you should write `tensec = song[:10000]`
2. `AudioSegment().raw_data` (also accessible as `._data` but you shouldn't use the private attribute) is the raw bytes data contained by the `AudioSegment`. On python 2 this is a `bytestring`, on python 3 it's a `bytes` object.
3. `numpy.fromstring()` exists because in python 2 raw byte data is usually stored as a string, which don't lend themselves to numeric operations. If you want to use the numeric values of the audio samples, you can also use [`AudioSegment().get_array_of_samples()](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/API.markdown#audiosegmentget_array_of_samples) which does pretty much the same thing, but accounts for whether it's 8/16/32 bit audio, and whether it's mono or stereo.

I implemented a low-pass filter ([source on github](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/pydub/effects.py#L187)) using the `get_array_of_samples()` method, which you may also find useful as an example